# how can i add this variable to my path for ifstream?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to append my path and contain a variable as part of the path but I'm getting an error.

What's wrong with it?

```
fstream fin("E:\\Games\\maps\\" + this->MapNumber + ".map", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
```

> this->MapNumber is a USHORT
>
> error:     13  IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Comment: If `this-MapNumber` is a number, then of course you can't concatenate it with a `const char *`. You probably have to do some casting or use `std::stringstream`.

Comment: You're jumped to the conclusion that you can concatenate a `const char[N]` to an `unsigned short` in C++ with the symbol `+`, but this is not and has never been true. Which [C++ book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources) are you using?

Comment: I'm not using a book, Just googling my way through

Answer (score 2):

In **C++** you can't use `+` to concatenate literal strings. You can use `+` with `std::string`s to concatenate them, but that won't work with *integer* or other types. You need to use a *stream* instead. Insertion and extraction into a *stream* will cause the types that support it to represent themselves as text, but you probably already knew this from general *I/O*.

Try with something like this:

```
std::stringstream filename;
filename << "E:\\Games\\maps\\" << this->MapNumber << ".map";

std::fstream fin(filename.str().c_str(), ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
```

Just like with everything else, to use something you need to *include* the header that declares it first. In order to use `std::stringstream` you need to include `<sstream>`.

Comment: @Dean: Maybe including `<sstream>` ?

Comment: @K-ballo: Develop it _before_ you click "Submit".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Sorry, I like to start from the bare basis and then gradually improve my answers...

Comment: Or just make a `std::string filename = "E:\\games\\maps\\"; filename = filename + this->MapNumber + ".map"; std::fstream fin(filename.c_str, ...);` - a little more lightweight than creating a stringstream just to get a string, I think.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Have you actually tried that? A character with the numeric value of `MapNumber` would be inserted, instead of the textual representation of `MapNumber`.

Comment: Doh! It's been a while since I did string work in C++... (Or anything much else in C++, for that matter...)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use operator+ on a string and another type like string or so you can either:

Option1: turn all variables into strings to append them

```
string s = string("E:\\Games\\maps\\") + string(itoa(this->MapNumber)) + string(".map");
```

option2: use stringstream as @k-ballo explained

option3: use the good old C fprintf (my personal favourite)

```
char str[100];
fprintf(str, "E:\\Games\\maps\\ %d .map", this->MapNumber);
```